# Is $S $ a subspace of $M_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is this a subspace $S=\left\{A\in M_3:\:\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\in R\left(A\right)\right\}$
of $M_{3x3}(\mathbb{R})$

The usual way to check is to choose two vectors from the subspace and check if their addition gives back a vector from the same subspace, but what do vectors from this space look like? The condition states that such a vector must have (1,1,1) in it's column space, how to choose such vectors?

P.S. Also in my opinion it's not a subspace because choosing the zero matrix we find out that it is not in $S$.

Comment: What does $R\left(A\right)$ mean precisely?

Comment: Isn't $R(A)$ usually denoted the **row space** and not the **column space**?

Comment: Mr @Travis it's not so it should not be a subspace?

Comment: Correct, as you indicate, every vector subspace must include the zero element.